# re-direct to new page on button click in React js

Tags: reactjs, redirect, button

can we use the `<a>` tag in reactjs for the re-direction to a page
Currently, I have used that for linking, and for some reason, it's not working

also, I have used `Link` `Route` `useHistory` for the re-direction, and even they are not working

I have added one `button` in the table, and I want that to `redirect` to a new page when clicked

with `useHistory` I have imported that in my js file

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

I have used that in my `export function`

```
let history = useHistory();
  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/bookingSlot");
  }
```

used `handleClick()` in `button`

```
 <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
    Click Me!
 </button>
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../scss/components/table';
import data from '../../public/userData';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ReservedListView() {
  console.log('data :' + JSON.stringify(data));
  let header = Object.keys(data[0]);
  console.log('header :' + header);

  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/bookingSlot");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table id="students" class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>SimeSlot</th>
          </tr>
          {data.map((el, index) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{el.name}</td>
              <td>{el.date}</td>
              <td>{el.day}</td>
              <td>{el.timeSlot}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="4"> 
            {/* buttons with usehistory()*/}
              <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
                Click Me Button!
              </button>

            {/* button with <a> tag */}
              <a href="/bookingSlot.js">Click Me!</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when I `click` on the `first button`
I am getting this **Error**

[image]

let me know if I am doing it in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

As per your current code things should work fine, Check this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-rmc2n?file=/example.js:787-849) it may help.

Comment: Thank You! for this, will take a look and figure out the actual issue with my code